# Get original url from after redirect in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

Are there any ways to get original redired URL from external service in Spring Boot? for example, if http://example.com/redirect redirects to my application with route http://localhost/test, can I extract "http://example.com/redirect"?

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: No.

This isn't really a Spring or Java question, so I won't address that.

Any information you need should be present in your redirect URL. Typically, this is useful in scenarios where you would want to redirect a user back to a specific page after performing an action.

Say I try to access `/user-profile` but I'm not logged in. I would be redirected to `/login` since `/user-profile` requires that a user be logged in. However, for a seamless user experience, I'd prefer to send the user back to `/user-profile` after successful login.

To achieve this, I wouldn't actually redirect the user to `/login`, but `/login?return_to=%2Fuser-profile`. Now, when I receive the request at `/login`, I look for the `return_to` parameter. That tells me where the user came from, and I'm able to send them back to that location after they have successfully logged in.